# which is the proper syntax for javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var age = prompt("Enter your age");
  if (age < 18){
   alert("Sorry, you are too yound to drive this car. Powering off");
   }
  else if (age > 18){
   alert("Powering On. Enjoy the ride!");
   }
  else if(age == 18){
   alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!");
   }
```

or

```
var age = prompt("What is your age?");

  if (Number(age) < 18) {
    alert("Sorry, you are too yound to drive this car. Powering off");
  } 
  else if (Number(age) > 18) {
    alert("Powering On. Enjoy the ride!");
  } 
  else if (Number(age) === 18) {
    alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!");
  }
```

which of the syntax is better? and why?...relating to the Boolean condition of the if/else...if statement

Comment: I would just use `Number()` once, when assigning the variable, rather than repeat it every time.

Comment: Don't do `age < 18` since the output of `prompt` is a string.

Comment: @asyncawait Not sure what that has to do with the question about whether to use `Number()`

Comment: The first version is simply wrong. See what happens if you enter `100`.

Comment: "What is the purpose of using `Number` on user input obtained with `prompt`" may be a more descriptive title - both is syntactically completely fine, the first however semantically won't do what you intend to.

Comment: This question is *way* too opinion based for Stack Overflow, see what’s considered on topic in the [help/on-topic]. You may consider instead posting on SO’s sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a question of syntax, the code you provided is good in any cases. However, if you want an accurate result and a clean code, you should transform your prompted result into a number. Keep in mind that Javascript in a dynamic typed language, so if the number as a string is compared to a number, they both will be compared as string.